# How does kernel get an executable binary file running under linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, executable, execve

How does kernel get an executable binary file running under linux?

It seems a simple question, but anyone can help me dig deep? How the file is loaded to memory and how execution code get started?

Can anyone help me and tell what's happening step by step?

Answer (score 45):

**Best moments of the `exec` system call on Linux 4.0**

The best way to find all of that out is to GDB step debug the kernel with QEMU: [How to debug the Linux kernel with GDB and QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642#33203642)

- `fs/exec.c` defines the system call at `SYSCALL_DEFINE3(execve`

  Simply forwards to `do_execve`.
- `do_execve`

  Forwards to `do_execveat_common`.
- `do_execveat_common`

  To find the next major function, track when return value `retval` is last modified.

  Starts building a `struct linux_binprm *bprm` to describe the program, and passes it to `exec_binprm` to execute.
- `exec_binprm`

  Once again, follow the return value to find the next major call.
- `search_binary_handler`

  - Handlers are determined by the first magic bytes of the executable.

    The two most common handlers are those for interpreted files (`#!` magic) and  for ELF (`\x7fELF` magic), but there are other built-into the kernel, e.g. `a.out`. And users can also register their own though [/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt)

    The ELF handler is defined at `fs/binfmt_elf.c`.

    See also: [Why do people write the #!/usr/bin/env python shebang on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-the-usr-bin-env-python-shebang-on-the-first-line-of-a-pyt/40938801#40938801)
  - The `formats` list contains all the handlers.

    Each handler file contains something like:

    ```
    static int __init init_elf_binfmt(void)
    {
        register_binfmt(&elf_format);
        return 0;
    }
    ```

    and `elf_format` is a `struct linux_binfmt` defined in that file.

    `__init` is magic and puts that code into a magic section that gets called when the kernel starts: [What does __init mean in the Linux kernel code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832114/what-does-init-mean-in-the-linux-kernel-code)

    Linker-level dependency injection!
  - There is also a recursion counter, in case an interpreter executes itself infinitely.

    Try this:

    ```
    echo '#!/tmp/a' > /tmp/a
    chmod +x /tmp/a
    /tmp/a
    ```
  - Once again we follow the return value to see what comes next, and see that it comes from:

    ```
    retval = fmt->load_binary(bprm);
    ```

    where `load_binary` is defined for each handler on the struct: C-style polymorsphism.
- `fs/binfmt_elf.c:load_binary`

  Does the actual work:

  - parse the ELF file according to the ELF specification, here is an overview of the ELF file format: [How to make an executable ELF file in Linux using a hex editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294034/how-to-make-an-executable-elf-file-in-linux-using-a-hex-editor/30648229#30648229)
  - set up the process initial program state based on the parsed ELF file, most notably:

    - initial register setup in a `struct pt_regs`
    - initial [virtual memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work) setup, the memory is specified in the ELF segments: [What's the difference of section and segment in ELF file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361248/whats-the-difference-of-section-and-segment-in-elf-file-format/38117710#38117710)
    - call `start_thread`, which marks the process as available to get to be scheduled by the scheduler
- eventually the scheduler decides to run the process, and it must then jump to the PC address stored in `struct pt_regs` while also moving to a less privileged CPU state such as Ring 3 / EL0: [What are Ring 0 and Ring 3 in the context of operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717016/what-are-ring-0-and-ring-3-in-the-context-of-operating-systems/44483439#44483439)

  The scheduler gets woken up periodically by a clock hardware that generates interrupts periodically as configured earlier by the kernel, for example [the old x86 PIT](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/tree/62ed931615ca33002431726d4b1e59f4aba21dd6#pit) or the [ARM timer](https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#arm-timer). The kernel also registers handlers which run the scheduler code when the timer interrupts are fired.

TODO: continue source analysis further. What I expect to happen next:

- the kernel parses the INTERP header of the ELF to find the dynamic loader (usually set to `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`).
- if it is present:

  - the kernel mmaps the dynamic loader and the ELF to be executed to memory
  - dynamic loader is started, taking a pointer to the ELF in memory.
  - now in userland, the loader somehow parses elf headers, and does `dlopen` on them
  - `dlopen` uses a configurable search path to find those libraries (`ldd` and friends), mmap them to memory, and somehow inform the ELF where to find its missing symbols
  - loader calls the `_start` of the ELF
- otherwise, the kernel loads the executable into memory directly without the dynamic loader.

  It must therefore in particular check if the executable is PIE or not an if it is place it in memory at a random location: [What is the -fPIE option for position-independent executables in gcc and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld/51308031#51308031)

Comment: "The formats list contains all the handler" , which file contains this format list??

Comment: @mysticTot the list is a variable: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/fs/exec.c#L72 , then each file `binfmt_` in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/v4.9/fs adds itself to that list using the magic `__init` thing. Also try to get the kernel source, and grep it ;-)

Comment: Got it.Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is missing alot context and dynamic linking formulation is very problematic, because the logic differs significantly between static and dynamic binary, see "The execution start address for the program is also set to be the entry point of the interpreter, rather than that of the program itself." in https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/

Answer (score 9):

Two [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) from the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) are relevant. The [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) system call (or perhaps `vfork` or `clone`) is used to create a new process, similar to the calling one (every Linux user-land process except `init` is created by `fork` or friends). The [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) system call replace the process address space by a fresh one (essentially by sort-of [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)-ing segments from the ELF executable and anonymous segments, then initializing the registers, including the stack pointer). The [x86-64 ABI supplement](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi-0.99.pdf) and the [Linux assembly howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) give details.

The dynamic linking happens after `execve` and involves the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so` file, which for ELF is viewed as an "interpreter".

Comment: It seems something to do with elf format and fork subroutine. And it could be also involved with /lib/ld-linux.so.2 to load those dynamic libraries.

Comment: `fork` is not a subroutine, it is a syscall, and as all system calls, it is an atomic operation from the application point of view. The ELF format is related to the `execve` system call (not to the `fork` one). And the `ld-linuc.so.2` dynamic loader is referenced inside the ELF executable so is related to `execve` and ELF.

Answer (score 8):

After reading the [ELF docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) already referenced, you should just [read the kernel code](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.1.4/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L559) that actually does it.

If you have trouble understanding that code, build a [UML Linux](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/), and you could step through that code in the debugger.

Comment: Indeed, the kernel code for this is very simple, unlike many other things in the kernel.

Comment: @R. agreed, even I can more or less understand it! Included a summary of the code path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31394861/895245

Answer (score 2):

You can start by understanding executable file formats, such as ELF.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format

The ELF file contains several sections with headers that describes how and where parts of the binary should be loaded into memory.

Then, I suggest reading up on the part of linux that loads binaries and handles dynamic linking, [ld-linux](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux).  This is also a good description of ld-linux: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~dww4s/articles/ld_linux.html

Comment: Thanks TJD. That's a good start. Can anyone give me a basic overview or picture of this question. Well, as a newbee, a full picture helps a lot. What do you think?

Comment: Actually the ld-linux has nothing to do with the kernel, and much more complicated than what the kernel does. Understanding how a statically-linked executable starts running is both easier, and what OP actually asked about.