# What does __init mean in the Linux kernel code?

Tags: c, linux

In the Linux kernel source code I found this function:

```
static int __init clk_disable_unused(void) 
{
   // some code
}
```

Here I can not understand what does `__init` means.

Comment: [Init Call Mechanism in the Linux Kernel](https://linuxgazette.net/157/amurray.html) also expands a little bit more and is worth to look at.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`include/linux/init.h`

```
/* These macros are used to mark some functions or 
 * initialized data (doesn't apply to uninitialized data)
 * as `initialization' functions. The kernel can take this
 * as hint that the function is used only during the initialization
 * phase and free up used memory resources after
 *
 * Usage:
 * For functions:
 * 
 * You should add __init immediately before the function name, like:
 *
 * static void __init initme(int x, int y)
 * {
 *    extern int z; z = x * y;
 * }
 *
 * If the function has a prototype somewhere, you can also add
 * __init between closing brace of the prototype and semicolon:
 *
 * extern int initialize_foobar_device(int, int, int) __init;
 *
 * For initialized data:
 * You should insert __initdata between the variable name and equal
 * sign followed by value, e.g.:
 *
 * static int init_variable __initdata = 0;
 * static const char linux_logo[] __initconst = { 0x32, 0x36, ... };
 *
 * Don't forget to initialize data not at file scope, i.e. within a function,
 * as gcc otherwise puts the data into the bss section and not into the init
 * section.
 * 
 * Also note, that this data cannot be "const".
 */

/* These are for everybody (although not all archs will actually
   discard it in modules) */
#define __init      __section(.init.text) __cold notrace
#define __initdata  __section(.init.data)
#define __initconst __section(.init.rodata)
#define __exitdata  __section(.exit.data)
#define __exit_call __used __section(.exitcall.exit)
```

Answer (score 73):

These are only macros to locate some parts of the linux code into special
areas in the final executing binary.
`__init`, for example (or better the `__attribute__ ((__section__
(".init.text")))` this macro expands to) instructs the compiler to mark this
function in a special way. At the end the linker collects all functions
with this mark at the end (or beginning) of the binary file.

When the kernel starts, this code runs only once (initialization). After it runs, the
kernel can free this memory to reuse it and you will see the kernel
message:

> Freeing unused kernel memory: 108k freed

To use this feature, you need a special linker script file, that tells the
linker where to locate all the marked functions.

Comment: Clever!  So that is what "Freeing unused kernel memory: 108k freed" meant. :-) I have sort of wondered all these years. I assumed it was some kind of buffers or something, not code.

Answer (score 7):

This demonstrates a feature of kernel 2.2 and later. Notice the change in the definitions of the `init` and `cleanup` functions. The `__init` macro causes the `init` function to be discarded and its memory freed once the `init` function finishes for built-in drivers, but not loadable modules. If you think about when the `init` function is invoked, this makes perfect sense.

[source](http://fixunix.com/embedded/5276-what-__init-linux-kernel-code.html)

Answer (score 6):

__init is a macro defined in ./include/linux/init.h which expands to `__attribute__ ((__section__(".init.text")))`.

It instructs the compiler to mark this function in a special way.  At the end the linker collects all functions with this mark at the end (or begin) of the binary file. When the kernel starts, this code runs only once (initialization). After it runs, the kernel can free this memory to reuse it and you will see the kernel

Answer (score 3):

Read comment (and docs at the same time) in [linux/init.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init.h).

You should also know that gcc has some extensions made specially for linux kernel code and it looks like this macro uses one of them.

Answer (score 3):

When you compile and insert a Linux kernel module into the kernel the first function to be executed is __init.This function is basically used to perform initialization before you perform the main operations like registering a device driver etc, There is another function with the opposite effect __exit which is called when you remove the kernel module which is again used to remove some registered device or any such similar function