# __init and __exit macros usage for built-in and loadable modules

Tags: init, exit

I was reading about linux kernel development and I just read some text that I don't understand. Here is the paragraph, which talks about the __init and __exit macros for modules:

> This demonstrates a feature of kernel 2.2 and later. Notice the change
> in the definitions of the init and cleanup functions. The __init macro
> causes the init function to be discarded and its memory freed once the
> init function finishes for built−in drivers, but not loadable modules.
> If you think about when the init function is invoked, this makes
> perfect sense.
>
> There is also an __initdata
> which works similarly to __init but for init variables rather than
> functions.
>
> The __exit macro causes the omission of the function when
> the module is built into the kernel, and like
> __exit, has no effect for loadable modules. Again, if you consider when the cleanup function runs

I get the point; the macro `__init` causes the  init function to be discarded and its memory freed once the init function finishes for built-in drivers. But *why?* not for loadable modules? I couldn't make sense of it.

I know it's a silly thing, but I thought about it for some time and couldn't comprehend it fully. Why for built-in driver but not for loadable modules? Variables, addresses etc assigned in `__init` would be required for the both, right?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x281.htm (from The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide) contains the relevant passage for anyone interested.  I think in this case the writer wasn't paying enough attention to what he was saying -- it only makes perfect sense once you understand the details of kernel memory organization!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right; even in a module there could be functions that you really don't need after initialization, and so they could in principle be removed from memory.  The reason `__init` has no effect for modules is more about how easy it would be to implement.

[This answer to a question about the nature of `__init`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8832142/460258) sheds some light on the subject.  Essentially, the kernel build system looks for all of the functions flagged with `__init`, across all of the pieces of the kernel, and arranges them so that they will all be in the same block of memory.

Then, when the kernel boots, it can free that one block of memory all at once.

This pre-sorting idea doesn't work so well with modules.  The init code has to be loaded when the module is loaded, so it can't share space with other init code.  Instead, the kernel would have to pick a few hundred bytes out of each module and free them individually.

However, hardware page sizes are typically 4KB, so it's hard to free up memory in chunks of less than that.  So trying to free the `__init` functions in each individual module is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks @Jander for the explanation. So for prebuilt modules - a pre defined memory block where the __init's are initialized is freed. Makes sense now. But is there any memory clean up operation for loadable modules? Or they are considered negligible to be ignored.

Comment: Nope -- as far as I know, there is no such memory cleanup for loadable modules.