# Use of __exit token in linux kernel

Tags: linux, module, kernel, init

What is the use of __exit token in loadable linux kernel modules and kernel in general? I see the explation for __init in /include/linux/init.h but couldn't find a general or particular (for the case loadable modules) anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple - __exit marks code that is used in module destruction. If you compiled a feature as built-in into the kernel and not a module or under configuration that forbids kernel module unload (yes, there is one), that code doesn't need to be loaded to RAM.

Comment: Thank you for your precise answer. This makes sense. But then I suppose it's of no use for loadable modules which  I intend to insert and remove? On a related note, __init is used in the loadable modules right? I read at some places that it's too much work to delete __init code segment for loadable modules, but on my experiment, as noted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283448/is-init-attribute-used-in-loadable-kernel-modules , it seems that __init does have an influence on loadable modules as well..