# Compilation error expected

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I came across the following declaration in the device driver programming:

```
static int __init sum_init(void)
```

I have seen `static int sum_init(void)`. Why does the above declaration not give compilation errors?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832114/what-does-init-mean-in-this-linux-kernel-code and here http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x281.htm

Comment: Thanks for the links Binyamin

Answer (score 2):

Because probably `__init` is some sort of `#define` that is assigned to anything that won't cause a compilation error.

```
#define __init
```

Or...

```
#define __init __section(.init.text) __cold notrace
```

Comment: That is usually not correct ( in context of linux device drivers)

Comment: Clarified :)  I didn't realize the poster is speaking about Linux drivers. Anyway, __init is just a macro that could expand to nothing, or to something that makes no harm. The confussion seems to be that the poster is not familiarized with GCC extensions to function declarations.

Answer (score -1):

Its just like saying:

> static int __init sum_init()
>
> {
>
> > ```
> >     return 0;
> > ```
> >
> > }

It doesn't return any value so no errors were occurred.

Comment: But your function does return a value: 0, and indeed it has to, as it's declared to return an int.

Comment: No it's not. (And I think you miss the actual question, maybe because it wasn't so clear to begin with)