# Kernel module source file after preprocessing

Tags: c, linux, macros, linux-kernel

Let we've written the following simplest module source file:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int __init md_init(void){
    printk("Hello kernel");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit md_exit(void){
    printk("Goodbye kernel");
}

module_init(md_init);
module_exit(md_exit);
```

How can I see this source after preprocessing? I want to know how are `__init` and `__exit` macros deployed and what's the `module_init(md_init)` and `module_exit(md_exit)`? How it works?

Comment: fyi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832114/what-does-init-mean-in-the-linux-kernel-code

Comment: Are you looking for [`gcc -E`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-E-81)?

Comment: @Nemo How it to use in my case? When we're writting the kernel Makefile we're using a sub-make which conatains at `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only plan to get the preprocessed output of kernel module, don't use Makefile, cause Makefiles (sub-make) will try to produce an object file with ability to insert into the kernel. Which contradicts with `gcc -E`, which just stops after preprocessing. So, just do the followings by using `gcc`:

```
  gcc -E new.c -I$TREE/include -I$TREE/arch/x86/include -I$TREE/include/uapi
```

`-E` is to get the preprocessed output, $TREE is the location of your kernel tree and if you use other arch then change x86. And we know that, `gcc` takes include dir parameter with `-I`, so pass all the kernel include dir through `-I`. Hope this helps!

Comment: fatal error: linux/init.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: I've tested the posted solution. And, linux/init.h should be under kernel include/ directory, mind checking it again?

Answer (score 9):

If you have your driver in the kernel, you can get it by doing:

```
make path-to-module/srcfile.i
```

As an example, I created a test directory under drivers/staging/, put your file in there, created a simple Kconfig and Makefile, updated the Kconfig and Makefile in staging, then ran

```
make drivers/staging/test/test.i
```

If you have the source outside the kernel tree, but have a Kconfig and Makefile set up, then:

```
make -C /path/to/kernel/src M=/path/to/driver srcfile.i
```

The result was of init and exit macros:

```
static int __attribute__ ((__section__(".init.text"))) __attribute__((__cold__)) __attribute__((no_instrument_function)) md_init(void)
{
 printk("Hello kernel");
 return 0;
}

static void __attribute__ ((__section__(".exit.text"))) __attribute__((__used__)) __attribute__((__cold__)) __attribute__((no_instrument_function)) md_exit(void)
{
 printk("Goodbye kernel");
}
```

Comment: For the out-of-tree case, "make -C $kbuild M=/path/to/driver srcfile.i"  also works

Answer (score 6):

,To see the intermediate files. i.e the .i files and .s files after the compiler pre-processing,  change the Makefile and add **EXTRA_CFLAGS=’-save-temps’**

**Makefile:**

> make -C /usr/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd)
>   modules EXTRA_CFLAGS=’**-save-temps**’

after this, once you run 'make' you can see the your_module_filename.i in

> ls /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/{your_modulename.i}

and the source with pre-processor changes will be available almost at the end of the file.

Comment: Cleaner and straightforward for who have an working makefile!

Answer (score 2):

The way to capture the correct preprocessed translation unit for a kernel source file is to first determine the exact command line that is being used to compile the `.o`. Then run the same command line, but add `-E`.  Also, change the `-o` option.

To obtain the full kernel command line you have to add `V=1` to the `make` command line. To avoid searching through a long, verbose log, build everything first, then just remove the `.o` in question, and rebuild with `V=1`.

For instance, I'm compiling for `arm` using a gcc called `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`. To get the preprocessed version of `kernel/spinlock.c`, this works in my case:

`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`**`-E`**`-B arm-linux-gnueabi- -Wp,-MD,kernel/.spinlock.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/include -I/personal/localhome/kaz/git/kernel/arch/arm/include -Iarch/arm/include/generated -Iinclude  -include include/generated/autoconf.h -D__KERNEL__ -mlittle-endian -Iarch/arm/mach-capri/include -Iarch/arm/plat-kona/include -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -marm -fno-dwarf2-cfi-asm -mabi=aapcs-linux -mno-thumb-interwork -funwind-tables -D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=7 -march=armv7-a -Uarm -mfpu=vfp3 -mfloat-abi=softfp -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fno-stack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fomit-frame-pointer -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO    -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(spinlock)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(spinlock)" -c`**`-o kernel/spinlock.prepro.c`**`kernel/spinlock.c`

I cut and pasted the line from the verbose compiler output, added `-E` and changed `-o` to capture the output in a file. (You can remove the `-o <arg>` to get it on standard output, of course).

Of course, many of the options in that command line do not affect preprocessing, but some do, such as anything that defines a macro, alters the include paths.

You don't want to be guessing at these things manually.

Note that if you invoke `make` using `make -C <dir> ...`, then `make` changes directory to `<dir>` before doing anything. It reads the `Makefile` from that directory, and so forth; it is almost the same as executing the command `(cd <dir>; make ...)`. In this case, the command line that you get out of the build output will contain relative paths that only resolve in `<dir>`; change to `<dir>` before trying to run the command, or wrap it with `(cd <dir>; <command>)`.

Comment: I get the following warning:
fatal error: generated/autoconf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: What compilation command you are using here was generated was based on .config file particularly those *defined macros* which might change the include paths or so, since those are config driven so it's also a question of how you'll treat them. After this I don't see any good points for your answer.

Comment: @rakib I suspect you are in the wrong directory. Did you run `make -C <dir> ...`? If so, the compiler command lines are relative to `<dir>`.

Comment: I can compile the module from that directory and can extract the `V=1` output. As per your answer - that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

In Makefile just add below flags, this will save ".i" and ".s" files-
DEBUG_CFLAGS    := -save-temps

Answer (score 0):

A quick but (very) dirty method, if you do not need anything else than preprocessing, is to put the line ccflags-y += -E in the Makefile of the module. The generated .o files are then actually the preprocessed output files.