# two variables when defining function

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I understand that you define a function using this format

```
return_type function_name(args)
{
    ... body ...
}
```

But then I see this code from the kernel: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/time/tick-broadcast.c#L995L1005

where a function definition looks like this:

```
void __init tick_broadcast_init(void)
{
    ... body ...
}
```

It looks like there's two variables, `__init` and `tick_broadcast_init`.  Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Between the return type and the function name there may be compiler-specific attributes (such as directives governing the section of the executable, the calling convention and other stuff). This is the case for `__init` (actually a macro which expands to several of these attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init` and `tick_broadcast_init` are not variables.

`__init` is a a macro see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832114/what-does-init-mean-in-the-linux-kernel-code) for more explanations.

`tick_broadcast_init` is your function name.

Your return type is `void` meaning "nothing" so that there is in fact no data in return.