# Linux Kernel function memblock_alloc_range_nid is not present in the address space

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86, gdb, qemu

I'm trying to debug physical memory allocation to understand what part of the Linux Kernel use [memblock_alloc_range_nid](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19-rc2/source/mm/memblock.c#L1354) on `x86-64` and how.

I'm running the latest `Linux Kernel 5.19-rc2` built from upstream with `Ubuntu 20.04` inside QEMU. The problem is it's not possible to access memory address the function `memblock_alloc_range_nid` is located at. While other Kernel functions can be easily disassembled.

Here is what I have in my `gdb` connected to the QEMU VM:

```
(gdb) disas memblock_alloc_range_nid
Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffff831a05d1
(gdb) disas native_safe_halt
Dump of assembler code for function native_safe_halt:
#...
End of assembler dump.
```

What's wrong with the function `memblock_alloc_range_nid`? Why is it not possible to access its address? It seems all the function from [`memblock.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19-rc2/source/mm/memblock.c) cannot be accessed.

Comment: It seems the function is marked as [`__init`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832114/what-does-init-mean-in-the-linux-kernel-code).

Comment: Not sure, but maybe it has to do sth with the [`__init`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8832142/13998163) attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Margaret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72722745/linux-kernel-function-memblock-alloc-range-nid-is-not-presented-in-the-address-s#comment128459214_72722745) and [Roi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72722745/linux-kernel-function-memblock-alloc-range-nid-is-not-presented-in-the-address-s#comment128459216_72722745) have noted in the above comments, `memblock_alloc_range_nid()` is annotated with `__init`. Functions annotated with `__init`, `__head` and similar macros are only needed during kernel initialization right after boot. After the kernel has finished initializing things, the special memory section containing all those functions is unmapped from memory since they are not needed anymore.

If you want to debug any such function, you will have to break very early, for example at `start_kernel()`, then you can inspect the function or set a breakpoint and `continue` execution to hit it.

Important: add `-S` (uppercase) to your QEMU command line options to make it stop and wait for the debugger before starting the kernel, and start the kernel with KASLR disabled using `-append "nokaslr"` (or adding `nokaslr` if you are already specifying `-append`).

The following GDB script should be what you need:

```
$ cat script.gdb
directory /path/to/kernel-source-dir
file /path/to/kernel-source-dir/vmlinux

target remote localhost:1234

break start_kernel
continue
```

Launch `gdb -x script.gdb` (after starting QEMU), and when you hit the `start_kernel` breakpoint, you can add another one for `memblock_alloc_range_nid`, then `continue`:

```
0x000000000000fff0 in exception_stacks ()
Breakpoint 1 at 0xffffffff82fbab4c

Breakpoint 1, 0xffffffff82fbab4c in start_kernel ()
(gdb) b memblock_alloc_range_nid
Breakpoint 2 at 0xffffffff82fe2879
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0xffffffff82fe2879 in memblock_alloc_range_nid ()
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function memblock_alloc_range_nid:
=> 0xffffffff82fe2879 <+0>:     push   r15
   0xffffffff82fe287b <+2>:     mov    r15,rcx
   0xffffffff82fe287e <+5>:     push   r14
   0xffffffff82fe2880 <+7>:     mov    r14,rdx
   0xffffffff82fe2883 <+10>:    push   r13
   0xffffffff82fe2885 <+12>:    mov    r13d,r9
   ...
```

Comment: The problem was that I ran Ubuntu simply as running qemu image. QEMU needs to be run with `-kernel` option, otherwise it produce the same memory access error even at the very startup.  Do you have idea why?

Comment: @SomeName I don't really understand what you are talking about. Of course you need `-kernel` to select the kernel. You need to *add* `-S` at the end of your QEMU command line. Keep everything else, and add `-S`. If you don't specify `-kernel` then QEMU has nothing to run so it's normal that it doesn't work. If you have a pre-packaged bootable image then you might be able to boot it even without `-kernel`, but that depends on your specific case.

Comment: I meant to run QEMU image with manually installed OS (Ubuntu 20.04 in my case) so it does not required `-kernel`. So if running qemu image with installed Ubuntu it's not possible to break on `start_kernel` due to the same memory error. This is what consfusing to me

Comment: I think I wasn't that clear about the source of confusion. I created a qemu image file. Then installed Ubuntu 20.04 and then installed kernel built from upstream. So next time I pass the actual image file as a parameter without `-kernel` option. And in that case It does not work with `-S` option due to the same memory access error.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question the qemu was running with Ubuntu 20.04, not just a kernel

Comment: @SomeName oh, I see. That's most probably because the kernel is running with KASLR enabled (which is the default). Use `-append "nokaslr"` (or add `nokaslr` in the `-append` string if you already have specified something in `-append`). That should work.

Comment: Nice point regarding `nokaslr`, thanks.