# What if I remove the __init prefix of the linux module init function

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have known that the __init will put the linux module init function into a special ELF section and can be overwrite by kernel after loading the module. But my question is that what if I remove this __init mark and what will happen? I try to write a simple demo without the __init prefix. So it only will keep the module init function code all the time until it is unloaded?

I tried search on google, stackoverflow and others, without finding same question and answer.
I expecting the answer.

Comment: Then its like all the rest of the code in the regular text section.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \_\_init mean in the Linux kernel code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832114/what-does-init-mean-in-the-linux-kernel-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mark it as `__init` the kernel build system will simply not know that it is an init function. As a result of this, it will not be placed in `.init.text`, but in `.text` along with other functions.

When the module is loaded into the kernel, after calling the function registered as `module_init()`, the kernel will remove the `.init.text` section, so in case your function is *not* marked as `__init` it will keep existing in memory.

A quick test with `/proc/kallsyms` confirms this.

- With a `modinit` function marked as `__init`:

  ```
  / # insmod test.ko
  / # cat /proc/kallsyms | grep -F [test]
  ffffffffc0000000 t modexit    [test]
  ffffffffc0000000 t cleanup_module [test]
  ```
- With a `modinit` function **not** marked as `__init`:

  ```
  / # insmod test.ko
  / # cat /proc/kallsyms | grep -F [test]
  ffffffffc0000000 t modinit    [test]
  ffffffffc0000003 t modexit    [test]
  ffffffffc0000003 t cleanup_module [test]
  ffffffffc0000000 t init_module    [test]
  ```

Comment: So if I didn't prefix __init in the driver init code. It doesn't really do any harm, it just wastes a little bit of memory, can I understand it like it？

Comment: @LongJack yes, that's about it.