# How does a loader in operating system work?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, kernel, system, bootloader

I know that a loader is a program which loads a program to the Main Memory. So,how does this actually works? What happens exactly? Actually when a loader loads a program, an entry in PCB is created and the program is put in a job pool. How the executable codes of a program are copied to the main memory? In simple how to load the codes of a file to the main memory using C or C++ ?

Comment: See also [MSDN: CreateProcess function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) and [MSDN: LoadLibraryEx function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 11):

This largely depends on the operating system. What I will write here is Linux specific, but the similar things happens on other operating systems.

First, the `fork()` call is initiated, effectively creating new process (and appropriate PCB entry). The next step is calling `exec` system call which will do the hard work. I'll assume that we're talking about ELF executables here.

In that case, after recognizing that this is the ELF executable (by inspecting magic number) `exec` will call `load_elf_binary` (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L664)

The argument `struct linux_binprm *bprm` that is passed to this function contains all the metadata about binary (already filled by `exec`) such is executable name, environment info, etc. (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/binfmts.h#L14)

The ELF program loading is a complex task, and it requires understanding of the ELF format.

The very good resource on this can be found [here](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf)

In a nutshell, these are interesting steps that kernel is performing:

- checks the elf headers to find if there's an program interpreter specified for this binary (`ld.so` is used for dynamically linking the required libraries, peforms the relocations, calls initialization functions for the linked libraries).
- Setup the new executable environment (setup the the new credentials, mark the point of no return, for example)
- Setup the memory layout (like randomize the stack) and map the pages from executable to memory
- Calls `start_thread` and starts either program or the interpreter (`ld.so`)

Good document on understanding of elf with interpreters can be found [here](http://s.eresi-project.org/inc/articles/elf-rtld.txt)

Resources:

- https://www.cs.stevens.edu/~jschauma/631/elf.html
- http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394861/133707
- http://s.eresi-project.org/inc/articles/elf-rtld.txt

Comment: Where is code that reads/interprets the ELF file?   Is it actually inside the OS running as some system process, or is it dropped into the new process VM running as the process?

Comment: In case of the ELF binary without program interpreter, it's all in the kernel (see linked `binfmt_elf.c` file). In case of ELF with program interpreter, part is done by OS (in the same file, `binfmt_elf.c`) and part for loading dynamic libraries, initializing them and relocating the main program is done by `ld.so` which is dropped into the new process.